# Google Cloud Container: Getting error "does not have edit permissions on project"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to create a Container Cluster in Google Container Engine using the console (UI).
I am getting the below error while creating a cluster of size - 3 of machine type "n1-standard-1"

```
"xxxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com" does not have edit permissions on project "xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx".
```

I have already enabled the API's related to Container management :-

1. Google Cloud Container Builder API
2. Google Container Engine API

Also, I haven't created a service account as given in the error `"xxxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"` . I don't know about this service-account? what is this used for? and who created it?

Though I have another service account, which is different from the one shown in error, it has all the edit permissions to my project.

Answer (score 1):

The `xxxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` is the service account that Google Container Engine uses to create the resources for your cluster. You'll need to make sure that it has "Editor" role in the [permissions section](http://console.developers.google.com/permissions) of your GCP project.

Comment: is it documented anywhere about this service-account?

Comment: Doesn't look like it :(. I'll make sure that gets fixed.

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/troubleshooting#error_400_missing_edit_permissions_on_account